# MySQL create table script with keys

Tags: mysql, create-table

I'm trying to execute this script on MySQL Server (installed on a VM with Ubuntu Server 64bit)

```
CREATE TABLE `MAINTABLEPARTS` (
   `NAME_PARTS` varchar(300) NOT NULL, 
   `BRAND` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
   `CODE_PART` varchar(105) NOT NULL, 
   `CODE_PARTS_ADVANCED` varchar(150) NOT NULL, 
   `CODE_PARTS_USERNUMBER` varchar(150) NOT NULL, 
   `EAN` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `STATUSPRODUCT` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `NAME_IMAGE` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `TTC_ART_ID` int(11) NOT NULL, 
   `ADDITIONAL_DATA` text, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`TTC_ART_ID`),
   KEY (`BRAND`, `CODE_PART`, `EAN`)
   KEY (`BRAND`, `CODE_PARTS_USERNUMBER`)
   )
```

The problem is that I get an error in the query when I execute it...(something about the sql version).... the script above is automatically generated so I did not write it myself. Any ideas what might could be wrong ? If you need any further information please let me know...(MySQL version 5.7.15, query executed from MySQL Front v5.4 - build 4.148)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma here

```
CREATE TABLE `MAINTABLEPARTS` (
   `NAME_PARTS` varchar(300) NOT NULL, 
   `BRAND` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
   `CODE_PART` varchar(105) NOT NULL, 
   `CODE_PARTS_ADVANCED` varchar(150) NOT NULL, 
   `CODE_PARTS_USERNUMBER` varchar(150) NOT NULL, 
   `EAN` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `STATUSPRODUCT` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `NAME_IMAGE` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `TTC_ART_ID` int(11) NOT NULL, 
   `ADDITIONAL_DATA` text, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`TTC_ART_ID`),
   KEY (`BRAND`, `CODE_PART`, `EAN`),
   ---------------------------------^
   KEY (`BRAND`, `CODE_PARTS_USERNUMBER`)
   )
```

Comment: Thanks ! With all those things and the code I write, it slipped my mind ! you're most welcome !